# How to extract a value and create new column based off of criteria

Tags: sql

I have a created column that has different timestamps based on status code. I want to extract the different timestamps and create new columns based off of what the status code is.

```
select C.RM_JOB_NO, 
C.DATE_CREATED,
to_char(cast((from_tz(cast(c.SEND_DATE_TIME AS TIMESTAMP),'00:00') AT TIME ZONE 'EST5EDT') AS DATE), 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') as CREATED, 
CASE
    WHEN (c.status_code = 'ADDORD' ) THEN 'Created'
    WHEN (c.status_code = 'ASGN' ) THEN 'Dispatched'
    WHEN (c.status_code = 'ENRT' ) THEN 'Enroute'
    WHEN (c.status_code = 'ARRIVE' ) THEN 'Onsite'       
    WHEN (c.status_code = 'NCLCMP' ) THEN 'Completed'
    WHEN (c.status_code = 'CGIL' ) THEN 'CGI'
    WHEN (c.status_code = 'CHGORD' ) THEN 'OrdChanged'
    WHEN (c.status_code = 'INTRPT' ) THEN 'Interrupt'
    else c.status_code
    END as "Status Code" ,
c.CREATOR_ID,
c.SERVICE_ID,
c.DISPATCH_CENTER,
c.PERSONNEL_ID_ONE,
d.RESOURCE_ID,
d.emp_id,
d.employee_name,
A.ST_NO, 
A.ST_NAME, 
A.CITY, 
A.ZIP,
A.GEO_COORD_X,
A.GEO_COORD_Y,
A.EXEC_CODE,
B.COND_FND_CD_1,
B.COND_FND_CD_2, 
B.COND_FND_CD_3, 
B.COND_FND_CD_4, 
B.COND_LFT_CD_1, 
B.COND_LFT_CD_2, 
B.COND_LFT_CD_3, 
B.COND_LFT_CD_4, 
B.COMP_INFO_CD, 
b.complete_date_time,
DetermineFieldCenter(a.Map_No, a.Grid_No, a.City, a.Zip, a.Order_SubType) "Field Center"
from fsa_order A, completion B, activity C, employee D
where A.RM_JOB_NO = B.rm_job_no
AND A.RM_JOB_NO=C.RM_JOB_NO
AND c.RESOURCE_ID=d.RESOURCE_ID
```

What I want to see is if status_code='Created' the new column 'time created" would contain the timestamp for the "created" status code. Same for the rest of the status codes